# Is it dead code in LinkedHashMap in JDK11？

Tags: java, java-8, java-11, linkedhashmap, dead-code

I am reading LinkedHashMap source code in JDK 11 and I found a piece of dead code(I'm not sure)

As we all know, LinkedHashMap use a doubly linked list to preserve the order of all the elements.It has a member called `accessOrder`

```java
final boolean accessOrder;
```

By default it is false, but if it is set to true, everytime you run `get`, it will move the element it gets to the end of the linked list.That is what the function `afterNodeAccess` do.

```java
//if accessOrder were set as true, after you visit node e, if e is not the end node of the linked list,
//it will move the node to the end of the linkedlist. 
    void afterNodeAccess(Node<K, V> e) {
        LinkedHashMap.Entry<K, V> last;

        if(accessOrder && (last = tail) != e) {

            //if enter `if` ，it indicates that e is not the end of the linked list, because (last=tail!=e)
            //then `a` as the after node of p(p is e after casting to LinkedHashMap.Entry) is never gonna be null. Only if p is last node of the linked list then a will be null.
            LinkedHashMap.Entry<K, V> p = (LinkedHashMap.Entry<K, V>) e, b = p.before, a = p.after;

            p.after = null;

            if(b == null) {
                head = a;
            } else {
                b.after = a;
            }

            // Is the if else clasue redundant? `a` must not be null.. the else clase will never be excuted.
            if(a != null) {
                a.before = b;
            } else {
                last = b;
            }

            if(last == null) {
                head = p;
            } else {
                p.before = last;
                last.after = p;
            }

            tail = p;

            ++modCount;
        }
    }
```

So here comes my problem:

`(accessOrder && (last = tail) != e` means e is not the last node of the linked list. If e is already the last node, we dont have to do anything right?

Then `a` as the after node of p, (p is e after casting to LinkedHashMap.Entry), it cant be null. Only if `p` is the last node then `a` can be null.

So what's the point of the following piece of code?

```java
 // Is the if else clasue redundant? `a` must not be null.. the else clase will never be excuted.
            if(a != null) {
                a.before = b;
            } else {
                last = b;
            }
```

`a` always `!= null` , the else clause `last = b` will never be executed....So is it dead code?

Also I do an experiment with `accessorder` set as `true`, then I `get` the last node in debug mode and it seems that I can't never get into the above else caluse `last = b`

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm not sure why this is getting any downvotes. It seems like a good question.

Comment: Seems to me that likewise, the subsequent `last == null` can never be `true`. Apparently, this is just copy&paste of general single linked list operations, without adapting it to the current case.

Comment: @JohnMercier: What makes me feel worried about this community is that your comment has already 7 upvotes while I see minimal support of the question itself (4 upvotes) (+1 mine) .

Comment: @Nikolas I think I am missing something. What conclusion am I supposed to make with your comment?

Comment: Why your comment is upvoted 8 times and the question only 5 times? If one agrees with your comment should also express the same feeling to the question. This is odd to me.

Comment: There is a lot of code like this in the OpenJDK. Feel free to submit a patch on [core-libs-dev mailing list](https://mail.openjdk.java.net/mailman/listinfo/core-libs-dev). Maybe your patch will be accepted. Good luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code provided in the OP is a node removal algorithm for a single linked list, which sets the removed node as the tail of the list (reposition to the tail):

```
        LinkedHashMap.Entry<K, V> current = (LinkedHashMap.Entry<K, V>) e
        LinkedHashMap.Entry<K, V> pred = current.before, succ = current.after;

        current.after = null;

        // position the successor of the removed node correctly 
        // (either as the head of the list or as the successor of the node BEFORE the removed node)
        if(pred == null) {
            head = succ;
        } else {
            pred.after = succ ;
        }

        // position the predecessor of the removed node correctly
        // (either as the tail of the list or as the predecessor of the node AFTER the removed node)
        if(succ != null) {
            succ.before = pred;
        } else { // unreachable for non tail nodes
            last = pred;
        }

        // final step - if the predecessor of the removed node was null then the head
        // of the list is the removed node (the list contains a single node).
        // otherwise update the removed node as the tail of the list -
        // its predecessor will be the previous tail of the list
        if(last == null) { // unreachable for non tail nodes
            head = current;
        } else { 
            current.before = last;
            last.after = current;
        }

        tail = current;
```

This algorithm handles all possible cases given a node that should be repositioned as the tail of the linked case.

In the context of the `afterNodeAccess` method, there will be some redundancy in the general case algorithm since the repositioned node is never at the tail of the list thanks to `(last = tail) != e`. Therefore, a more efficient algorithm would be:

```
        current.after = null;
        // position the successor of the removed node correctly 
        // (either as the head of the list or as the successor of the node BEFORE the removed node)
        if(pred == null) {
            head = succ;
        } else {
            pred.after = succ ;
        }

        // position the predecessor of the removed node correctly
        // (as the predecessor of the node AFTER the removed node)
        // update the removed node as the tail of the list -
        // its predecessor will be the previous tail of the list
        succ.before = pred;
        current.before = last;
        last.after = current;
        tail = current;
```

As [holger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2711488/holger) mentioned in the comments - this is a classic 'copy-paste' solution which IMHO shows that reusing code in some cases can seem to be inefficient and unclear.

As suggested by [Johannes Kuhn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/845414/johannes-kuhn), you can consider submitting a fix for the unreachable code to the OpenJDK community. See the references on how this can be done.

References:

- [Source code from AdoptOpen JDK 11 for LinkedHashMap](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk11/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/LinkedHashMap.java)
- [How to contribute a fix to OpenJDK](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/JDKUpdates/How+to+contribute+a+fix)